# python list_objects() only accepts keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I have created the following loop which obtains the path to certificates `CERTIFICATION_PATH`. It is made up of the path: bucket/organisation/uuid

```
import json
import boto3

for data in json_data:
    MQTT_TOPIC = "{organisation}/{device_vendor}/{device_type}".format(**data)
    CERTIFICATION_PATH = "{}/{organisation}/{uuid}".format(bucket, **data)
    
for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list): 
    result = client.list_objects(CERTIFICATION_PATH)
    print('-------------------')
    print(result)
    print('-------------------')
```

I'm getting the error `list_objects() only accepts keyword arguments.` when I do the above. Is there another way to list the objects in the `CERITIFCATION_PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just passing in a string (`CERTIFICATION_PATH` in your case), it is necessary to pass the `bucket` as well as the `prefix` separately into [`list_objects()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects).

You also need to use keyword arguments, which means, you have to pass in the parameters in the form `key=value`.

The following or similar should:

```py
client.list_objects(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix=f"{organisation}/{uuid}",
)
```

where `bucket`, `organisation`, and `uuid` need to be defined somewhere.

Comment: I tried this and sadly got the error ```Missing required parameter in input: "Bucket"
Unknown parameter in input: "bucket", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, Marker, MaxKeys, Prefix, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner
Unknown parameter in input: "prefix", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, Marker, MaxKeys, Prefix, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner
```

Comment: My apologies, it needs to be `Bucket` and `Prefix` instead of `bucket` and `prefix`. I updated the answer.